# We want to see where the traffic is going on a Cisco 1140 firewall.. is there a way to do this? Need more than hitcounts

Tags: cisco, firewall, cisco-firepower

looking to see if there is a way to find out where traffic is going and coming from on a Cisco 1140 running FTD .... We need more than just a hit count...

Comment: Are you running it in FTD or ASA mode?

Answer (score 0):

Clarify what you mean by 'where traffic is going', please. Do you mean you want some kind of graphical breakdown of source and destination pairs for connections? Full connection logging? Or interface packet/byte counters? Breakdown by protocol and port numbers? Application traffic ID and analysis?

If you are running that firewall in Firepower Threat Defense mode (not ASA mode) then it should pair well with the Firepower Management Center to help you manage the firewall and give you basic reporting for traffic via some graphs and other displays.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Y2Zw2wh62k

Otherwise you can look into netflow export from the firewall and related netflow traffic analyzer platforms that will take the data output from the firewall and turn it into pretty graphs and reports for you, like Solarwinds, ManageEngine, PRTG, etc.